# Testing RabbitMQ locally with Apache QPID - random port

Tags: java, testing, rabbitmq, qpid

I wanted to set up a little local test for some components connecting to RabbitMQ. For this, one solution seems to be the QPID In-Memory Broker and actually that works quite well when following [these instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/qpid/How+to+embed+Qpid+Broker-J) (only using the current version of 7.0.3 instead of 7.0.0)...

For Rabbit MQ, I removed the `"AMQP_1_0"` protocol and only added the qpid-`broker-plugins-amqp-0-8-protocol` dependency. Also I replaced the `Authenticationprovider` with a `PLAIN`. This was enough to get my `RabbitMQ` components working and sending/receiving messages through that `Broker`.

But the problem is this line...

```
"port" : "${qpid.amqp_port}",
```

As far as I understand it, this should allow me to define the port the broker is listening at by setting this property when calling `systemLauncher.startup`.

```
attributes.put("qpid.amqp_port", 12345);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and the Broker always listens at the default port (5672, iirc). Obviously this is not optimal for automated tests, so I am looking for one of the following possibilities (or a better one):

1. Putting a random port in the properties (I can find an open port myself, no problem) or...
2. Telling QPID to use a random (open) port - but then I also need to know which port is actually used, since `SystemLauncher` does not seem to offer any way to query that.

Comment: Hi Florian! It seems i have a very similar situation. i described it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345844/integration-tests-with-rabbitmq. I have a suspicios that i'm using qpid bloker incorrectly. Can u have a look at my question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apache Qpid Broker-J's `SystemLauncher` supports `SystemLauncherListeners` which get notified once a various points through the startup sequence.  If you configure the Broker to bind to port 0, a dynamically assigned port will be assigned at run-time.  You can then use an `#afterStartup()` implementation to determine which port has been bound.  Take a look at `PortExtractingLauncherListener` (test harness code) as an example to follow.

In Broker-J's model there is a distinction between an [object's attributes and context variables](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-7.0.3/book/Java-Broker-Management-Managing-Entities.html#Java-Broker-Management-Managing-Entities-General). If you want to provide a substitution for `qpid.amqp_port` you do this by providing a context variable. You can so this programmatically like so:

`attributes.put("context", Collections.singletonMap("qpid.amqp_port", 0))`

or, as context variables are defaulted from Java system properties, like this on the JVM command line `-Dqpid.amqp_port=0`