# Integration tests with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, integration-testing, amqp, spring-amqp, qpid

Currently i'm working on some Spring Boot 2.x application interacting w/ RabbitMQ.
I'd like to create an integration test to test the whole app. logic, including interaction w/ Rabbit. So far i need a light-weight stand-alone implementation of AMQP standart to make Spring Boot work w/ it, including sending & receiving messages. I had a look at Qpid sample [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/qpid/How+to+embed+Qpid+Broker-J)
 but it needs RabbitMQ running somewhere what is not very good for my IT. Are there some another mature light-weight stand-alone AMQP implementations?

Thanx in advance for any assist.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other question, I already moved away from that and wrote my own connection factory to wrap the whole stuff, but to get a QPID server running purely in memory, I basically followed the instructions here... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/qpid/How+to+embed+Qpid+Broker-J - this way you can start it up when the test boots up and shut it down afterwards, not requiring any actual IT changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but could u start qpid server alone w/o any other RabbitMQ servers? Using the sample i cannot send & receive messages w/o RabbitMQ server running as service on my machine

Comment: Afaik, yes, I was able to send some messages back then, but is has been a while, to be honest. I did not install a RabbitMQ on my machine back then (and nowadays I use docker whenever I need one running).

Comment: I got it working ok with QPID 6.1.6 while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364236/create-exchange-and-queues-in-qpid-broker/51359649#51359649). I never figured out how to launch a 7.0.x embedded broker. I put the project for that answer in [my sandbox](https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/so50364236).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for reply. I'll try to find out what i was doing incorrectly w/ qpid

Comment: Excellent! Now everything is fine

Comment: For a working 7.x example, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49234754/2039709.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Gary Russel [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345844/integration-tests-with-rabbitmq#comment89779217_51345844):

> I got it working ok with QPID 6.1.6 while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364236/create-exchange-and-queues-in-qpid-broker/51359649#51359649). I never figured out how to launch a 7.0.x embedded broker. I put the project for that answer in [my sandbox](https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/so50364236).